# Using Katex with React JS, The elements of the matrix are placed outside the matrix

Tags: html, css, reactjs, katex

When using Katex with React JS, The elements of the matrix are placed outside the matrix

```
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
 }
```

Sample image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYEHm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS code will make the elements render outside the matrix, since the float value is left.

Kindly remove the above line in the css file.